# Displaying table on click using node and ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a `view.ejs` file with a button and a table. When the button is clicked I want the table to be populated, the problem is that to populate the table the variable `viewtabObj` is used which is undefined until the function is called when the button is clicked. Here is the current code:

```
    <form action="/populatetable" method="get">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Populate Table">
    </form>

    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Complete</th>
            <th scope="col">Completion Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Identifier</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <% var x = 1 %>
          <% millViewObj.forEach(function(obj) { %>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row"><%= x %></th>
              <td><%= obj.complete %></td>
              <td><%= obj.completion_date %></td>
              <td><%= obj.id %></td>
          <% x++;}); %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Is there a way to render the table on the same page after the button is clicked so that I won't get the error for the undefined variable?

Comment: That will not work with EJS, the values will need to be rendered in ahead of time and processed to be then sent to user.

Comment: You can have your submit button on press, perform an XHR request to say /?tableget=simple and it'll respond with the values you can loop through to create that table fast. However if this is used data and often, it may be best to just have node tell EJS ahead of time that object to render in to the tables. Beyond that maybe create a hidden class that you remove when it's fetched this data or preload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the error for the undefined variable as follows:

```
<% if (locals.millViewObj) { %>
<% var x = 1 %>
   <% millViewObj.forEach(function(obj) { %>
   <tr>
      <th scope="row"><%= x %></th>
      <td><%= obj.complete %></td>
      <td><%= obj.completion_date %></td>
      <td><%= obj.id %></td>
<% x++;}); %>
<% } %>
```